# Python Selenium pulling child property from parent?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a webform for text in specific fields however i can't do it with xpath because some forms are missing fields which won't be included in the page when it loads (i.e. if /html/blah/blah/p[3] is the initials field for one form it might be first name on another form but have the same xpath. The structure for the fields is like this:

```
<p><strong>Initials:</strong> WT</p>
```

so using python selenium i'm doing
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Initials:')]")` which does successfully pull the "Initials:" text between the strong tags but i specifically need the child text after it, in this case WT. It has the attribute "nextSibling.data" which contains the WT value but from my googling i don't think its possible to pull that attribute with python selenium. Does anyone know a way to pull the WT text following the xpath query?

Comment: is there an public url?

Comment: @QHarr: no its a post login page, i can dump more of the html if needed but all the fields that i need are basically wrapped in a <p> tag under just a div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'WT' text is in a weird spot. I don't think it is actually a sibling per-se. The only way I know to grab that text would be to use `p_element.get_attribute('outerHTML')`, which in this instance should grab the string `'<p><strong>Initials:</strong> WT</p>'`. I doubt this is the cleanest solution, but here's a way to parse that text out:

```
strong_close_tag = '</strong>'
p_close_tag = '</p>'

p_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Initials:')]/parent")

print(p_element.get_attribute('outerHTML')[text.index(strong_close_tag)+len(strong_close_tag):text.index(p_close_tag)])
```

**OR --** use `p_element.get_attribute('innerHTML')`, which should return just `<strong>Initials:</strong> WT`. Then, similarly, grab the text after the `</strong>` closing tab, maybe like this:

```
p_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Initials:')]/parent")

print p_element.get_attribute('innerHTML').split("</strong>",1)[1]
```

Comment: Just tried that but it looks like the outerHTML attribute is just <strong>Initials:</strong>, it doesnt include the WT below it

Comment: Which element are you getting outerHTML from? `<strong>Initials:</strong>` is the correct outerHTML for the `strong` element, but for the `p` element the outerHTML will include the opening and closing `p` tags.

Comment: If you are using the xpath in your question, that is grabbing the wrong element for this technique. I included xpaths that, based on your example, *should* work. But I can't optimize them without seeing the source HTML.

Comment: i think the xpath for some reason doesn't work with the /parent at the end and is still pulling the <strong> element, your solution helped tho instead of targeting the child element under the strong, i just did initialsselect.find_element_by_xpath('..') to target the parent and pulled its innerText attribute. Thank you!